# Probability that k people choose the same set of n numbers

Tags: probability

How can I calculate the probability that **at least 2 people** out of $k$ people choose an identical set of $n$ numbers? The numbers are positive integers, starting with $1$, and every number only appears once. We assume that every person picks their numbers randomly.

Example:
$3$ people choose $5$ numbers between $1$ and $20$:

- Person 1: $5, 8, 10, 12, 13$
- Person 2: $4, 5, 6, 7, 8$
- Person 3: $5, 8, 10, 12, 13$

How likely is it that Person 1 and Person 3 picked the same numbers?

I would need the formula in a generic way so that $k$ and $n$ can vary. Any help is appreciated!
Bonus: How would I need to modify the formula if I want to know the probability that "**at least 3** people" choose the same numbers?

Comment: Are the numbers ordered? Is there a difference between picking $1,2,3,4,5$ and $5,4,3,2,1$?

Comment: no, there would be no difference, the order is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The probability that at least two people pick the same set of numbers is equal to $1-$ the probability that everybody picks different sets of numbers.

Comment: Thanks, so how can I calculate the probability that everybody picks different sets of numbers? Unfortunately my math skills are not very sophisticated...

Comment: @user2037036 Let's say the first person picks $k$ numbers. Then the second person can pick $k$ out of $n-k$ numbers. Do you know how to count this?